# Wiremock calling methods

Tags: java, wiremock

Is there a way to call java method every time server gets request?

```
wireMockServer.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/testpost"))
                .willReturn(onIncomingRequest()));
```

like this, so sever will call onIncomingRequest every time this stub is used.

Comment: What exactly is `onIncomingRequest()` going to do? Does WireMock need to execute something, or do you just want to have _something_ happen when a request gets fired?

Comment: @agoff In fact I want to store last request body and return it with like "/getlastrequest" stub. Only  way I found to do this is to rewrite that stub response every time new "/testpost" request is fired. So I want "to have something happen when a request gets fired".

Comment: So you'd like to do something like: First request to `/test` with body of `{ some: "value" }`, responds with 200 and empty body. Second request to `/test` with body of `{ some: "other value" }`, responds with 200 and `{ some: "value" }`?

Comment: @agoff more like second request to `/gettest` will respond with 200 and `{some value}`

Comment: So the request url for the previous request won't necessarily match the current request?

Comment: @agoff yes. I need to get request body from another url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve your desired behavior by writing a custom response transformer. The response transformer would query WireMock's requests admin endpoint to retrieve the most recent requests, and parse that data to form a response.

Pseudocode:

```java
public class LastRequestBody extends ResponseTransformer {
    public String getName() {
        return "LastRequestBody";
    }

    @Override
    public Response transform(Request request, Response response, FileSource files, Parameters parameters) {
        // Set up some client
        String wmRequests = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/__admin/requests" // update to whatever your WM base url is
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = HttpUrl.parse().newBuilder().build().toString();
        okhttp3.Response okhttpResponse = client.newCall(okHttpRequest).execute();

        // Parse WM response into JSON
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject responseObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(okhttpResponse.body().string());
        JSONArray requests = (JSONArray) responseObj.get("requests");
        JSONObject mostRecentRequest = (JSONObject) requests[0];
        String mostRecentRequestBody = mostRecentRequest.get("request").get("body").toString();

        // Return response that looks like the original request/response
        return Response.Builder.like(response).but().body(mostRecentRequestBody.toJSONString()).build();
 
    }
}
```

Above code might not be 100% correct, but the outline should be solid enough.

Check out the WM Admin page for more info on querying for [all requests.](http://wiremock.org/docs/api/#tag/Requests/paths/%7E1__admin%7E1requests/get)
(Other assumptions - I've used JSONSimple for parsing, and OkHttp3 for making the request to WM)

Answer (score 1):

The (most) correct way to do this is to implement a `PostServeAction`. See [this documentation page](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#post-serve-actions) and [WireMock's test cases](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/PostServeActionExtensionTest.java) for details.